# Registration form android studio to connect to server

Tags: java, php, android, html

No errors occur within when emulator is run on my android phone. Not sure if that the correct http:192.168....... When I run the app i enter the data and it says connecting to server but then says unfortunately the app crashed. Any Ideas.

BackgroundTask

```
package com.example.om.fitnessproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String > {

    String register_url =     "https://192.168.0.4/Fitnessplus/register.php";


    Context ctx;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Activity activity;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    public BackgroundTask(Context ctx){

        this.ctx = ctx;
        activity = (Activity)ctx;


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Connecting to server");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String method = params [0];

        if(method.equals("register"))
        {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(register_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection =     (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream =     httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new     OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String name = params[1];
                String email = params[2];
                String password = params[3];
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-    8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                stringBuilder.append(line+"\n");


            }
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            Thread.sleep(5000);

            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String json) {

    try {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
        JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        String code = JO.getString("code");
        String message = JO.getString("message");
        if (code.equals("reg_true"))
        {

            showDialog("Registration Success", message,code);

        }

        else if(code.equals("reg_false"))
        {
            showDialog("Registration failed", message, code);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

public void showDialog(String title,String message,String code)
{
 builder.setTitle(title);
    if(code.equals("reg_true")||code.equals("reg_false"))
    {
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            activity.finish();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    }

}


}
```

---

register
    package com.example.om.fitnessproject;

```
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;

 public class register extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText Name, Email, Pass, ConPass;
    Button reg_button;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_name);
        Email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_email);
        Pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_password);
        ConPass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.reg_con_password);
        reg_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reg_button);
        reg_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (Name.getText().toString().equals("") || Email.getText().toString().equals("") || Pass.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(register.this);
                builder.setTitle("Something went wrong");
                builder.setMessage("Please fill in all the field");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            } else if (!(Pass.getText().toString().equals(ConPass.getText().toString()))) {

                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(register.this);
                builder.setTitle("Something went wrong");
                builder.setMessage("Your passwords are not matching");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        Pass.setText("");
                        ConPass.setText("");
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }

            else {

                BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(register.this);
                backgroundTask.execute("register",Name.getText().toString(),Email.getText().toString(),Pass.getText().toString());


            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

---

Trace

```
04-18 20:42:35.360 26137-26137/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
 04-18 20:42:35.532 26137-26137/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject      W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path:     /data/app/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject-1/lib/arm64
 04-18 20:42:36.458 26137-26209/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject      D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
 04-18 20:42:36.520 26137-26209/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject      I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 63c06b2, I8366cd0437
                                                                                 Build Date                       : 10/21/15
                                                                                 OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.05.13.02
                                                                                 Local Branch                     : 
                                                                            Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BF64.1.2.9_v2
                                                                            Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                                 Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
 04-18 20:42:36.526 26137-26209/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject      I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
 04-18 20:42:59.950 26137-26209/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject      D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7f9623f800 (RippleDrawable)      with handle 0x7f96234220
 04-18 20:43:05.999 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject      W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:      java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for      certification path not found.
 04-18 20:43:05.999 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject      W/System.err:     at      com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImp      l.java:328)
 04-18 20:43:05.999 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103)
 04-18 20:43:05.999 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143)
 04-18 20:43:05.999 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
 04-18 20:43:05.999 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
 04-18 20:43:06.000 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:      341)
 04-18 20:43:06.000 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
 04-18 20:43:06.000 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
 04-18 20:43:06.000 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
 04-18 20:43:06.000 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
 04-18 20:43:06.000 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
 04-18 20:43:06.000 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
 04-18 20:43:06.000 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
 04-18 20:43:06.000 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:64)
 04-18 20:43:06.000 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:26)
 04-18 20:43:06.000 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
 04-18 20:43:06.001 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
 04-18 20:43:06.001 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
 04-18 20:43:06.001 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
 04-18 20:43:06.001 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
 04-18 20:43:06.001 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 04-18 20:43:06.001 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
 04-18 20:43:06.001 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:318)
 04-18 20:43:06.001 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:219)
 04-18 20:43:06.001 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:115)
 04-18 20:43:06.001 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:556)
 04-18 20:43:06.001 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
 04-18 20:43:06.001 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
 04-18 20:43:06.001 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:    ... 20 more
 04-18 20:43:06.001 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
 04-18 20:43:06.002 26137-26700/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject W/System.err:    ... 26 more
 04-18 20:43:06.010 26137-26137/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
 04-18 20:43:06.010 26137-26137/com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                         Process: com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject, PID: 26137
                                                                                         java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int      java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                                                                                             at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
                                                                                             at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
                                                                                             at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
                                                                                        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
                                                                                        at com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:115)
                                                                                        at com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:26)
                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
                                                                                        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Add the `Internet` permission to your manifest?

Comment: Don't just tell us it crashed, give us the stack trace.

Comment: Ive added the internet permission to the manifest which is <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>.

Comment: at com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:119)
                                                                                            at com.example.kieranbroom.fitnessproject.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:26)

Comment: @GabeSechan here is my stack trace

Comment: That's not the full trace.  The full trace has important info like the exception type.